# Why does audio stop playing on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, audio-player

Here's a CodePen of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://codepen.io/golfecholima/pen/GJqEOm

It's a little audio bug that sits in the bottom right corner. When a user scrolls past a certain element on the page the `<audio src="">` changes. Here's the jQuery:

```
// BRING IN YOUR AUDIO FILES HERE

var audioOne = 'https://d63kb4t2ifcex.cloudfront.net/201505horton/mp3/Horton_ImNotThisPicture.mp3';  // replace these with your audio files 
var audioTwo = 'https://d63kb4t2ifcex.cloudfront.net/201505horton/mp3/Horton_WeHadBackThen.mp3';  // replace these with your audio files
var audioThree = 'https://d63kb4t2ifcex.cloudfront.net/201505horton/mp3/Horton_IveNeverBeen.mp3';  // replace these with your audio files
var audioFour = 'https://d63kb4t2ifcex.cloudfront.net/201505horton/mp3/Dukakis_OneOfTheValuesofFurlough.mp3';  // replace these with your audio files

// SET YOUR SCROLL BREAKPOINTS HERE 

var breakOne = 0;
var breakTwo = $('.audio-two').offset().top - $(window).height();
var breakThree = $('.audio-three').offset().top - $(window).height();
var breakFour = $('.audio-four').offset().top - $(window).height();


// SET YOUR AUDIO FILE TITLES

var titleOne = 'LISTEN: The first audio file';
var titleTwo = 'LISTEN: The second audio file';
var titleThree = 'LISTEN: The third audio file';
var titleFour = 'LISTEN: The fourth audio file';

// DO THE STUFF

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioOne);
    audioElement.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
    //audioElement.load()
    $.get();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    }, true);

    // controls the playing of the audio

    $('.audioBug').click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('playing')) {
            audioElement.pause();
            $(this).removeClass('playing');
        } else {
            audioElement.play();
            $(this).addClass('playing');
        }
    });

    // collapses the bug 5 seconds after loading

    function removeBumper() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.audioBug > h6').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('.audioBug').animate({width: '4rem'}, 'fast');
            });
        }, 5000);
    }

    //hovering over the bug expands it to reveal the audio title. 

    $('.audioBug').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: '28rem'}, 'fast');
        $('.audioBug > h6').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.audioBug > h6').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('.audioBug').animate({width: '4rem'}, 'slow');
            });
        }, 1000);
    });

    //page loads, audio bug expands to reveal title, then collapses again
    setTimeout(function previewBug() {
        $('.audioBug').animate({width: '28rem'}, 'fast');
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.audioBug > h6').fadeIn(300, function() {
            removeBumper();
        });
    }, 2700);

    //scrolling through set ranges changes the audio file/title and expands the bug anew

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakOne && $(this).scrollTop() < breakTwo) {
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioOne);
            $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleOne);
        } 
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakTwo && $(this).scrollTop() < breakThree) {
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioTwo);
            $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleTwo);
        } 
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakThree && $(this).scrollTop() < breakFour) {
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioThree);
            $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleThree);
        } 
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakFour) {
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioFour);
            $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleFour);
        }
    });
```

It functions how I expect except that as soon as you start scrolling the audio stops even if the next break point hasn't been reached. My understanding is that `.scroll()` fires any time there's scrolling activity. So I can see where this would disrupt play if the function is constantly check to see which file should be in place.

Is there any way to keep that from happening. I've seen some AJAXy things that look like they might be the right idea but I'm too noobish to have figured that out just yet.

I've tried `setTimeout` which doesn't seem to help.

(I'm aware that the hover is a little wonky -- not worried about that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the src attribute is constantly set during scroll the browser will terminate current audio and start loading the "new" source (even if it is the same).

Here is a simple approach that may work with this specific problem, to check that the current source is not equal the source being checked for:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakOne && $(this).scrollTop() < breakTwo &&
     audioElement.src !== audioOne) {  // CHECK that it's not the same as current source

    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioOne);
    $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleOne);
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakTwo && $(this).scrollTop() < breakThree && audioElement.src !== audioTwo) {
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioTwo);
    $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleTwo);
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakThree && $(this).scrollTop() < breakFour  && audioElement.src !== audioThree) {
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioThree);
    $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleThree);
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakFour  && audioElement.src !== audioFour) {
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioFour);
    $('.audioBug > h6').text(titleFour);
  }
});
```

**[Modified CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdNKBo)**

There are other issues in code though, but that should help with the audio stopping due to constant reloading of new sources.

Comment: brilliant. Care to elaborate on the 'other issues'?

Comment: @george glad I could help! :) there are some "sync" issues with hovering, you can use clearTimeout etc. to fix, the div expanded to cover 100% of the window in some cases but I didn't check closer (probably related to the timer). I would suggest open a new post for those though (if necessary).

Comment: yeah the hover i'm aware of. on my list and thanks for the clearTimeout tip. i think i'll be able to fix that one without opening up another questions. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, without changing too much, would be to add a switch_audio function in your scroll event that would be called instead of your setAttribute. In that function you validate if you need to change the audio and if so you change it. Something like this:

```
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > breakOne && $(this).scrollTop() < breakTwo) {
    set_audio(audioOne, titleOne);           
  }
```

And your function:

```
function set_audio(which_audio, which_title){
    if(audioElement.src != which_audio){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', which_audio);
        $('.audioBug > h6').text(which_title);
    }
}
```